# How to avoid thumnails on facebook share popup window by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, url, facebook-sharer

Using below default button creation from facebook development plugins.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

How to say no thumbnails for share link?